# Displaying a Microsoft Office document in a WPF control

Tags: wpf, excel, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I am developing a WPF application that allows a user to browse the contents of a directory.  What I want to be able to do is, if the user clicks on a Microsoft Word or Excel doc, have the file display in a view control (like a Scrollviewer or something) within the WPF app.  I am attempting to make an all-in-one document viewer so the user doesn't have to open up separate Word and Excel windows.

The user does not need to be able to edit the file, just view it.  Additionally, the user WILL have Word and Excel installed on their computer.

Is this possible?  I am reading conflicting answers and it seems like there is an assumption that user doesn't necessarily have Office installed.  In this case, yes, they will have Office installed on their local machine.

Comment: I think maybe the "dsoFramer" control may be what you're looking for, but it seems to be "unsupported":  http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/08/24/hosting-office-in-a-wpf-application/

Comment: Sure I can do that on my macbook, also that way you run zero risk from gettting some unwanted virus. I dont know how tho I am afraid but since its built into mac os it can be built in windows.

Comment: if you have the open source code you could make it like explorer and instead of files, decent size previews. Just popped up in my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Spreadsheet control to open excel
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/spreadsheet

Sample location:
http://silverlight.syncfusion.com/samples/WPF/Samples/WPFSampleBrowser/UI/Spreadsheet/Spreadsheet.htm

To open word files use RichTextBox,
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/wpf/tools/features#rich-text-box

To open pdf use Pdfviewer,
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/report-viewer